# Kubernetes " Windows pods " not able to communicate with each other | “could not resolve host” | "failed to connect Network unreachable"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks, windows-container

I deployed three back-end services to kubernetes windows pods to ensure they communicate with each other. However, I found though containers, services, dns and end-points all are available and running but still when I try to access any of the services (Internally or externally) from one container to another it does not resolve the dns and receive “could not resolve host” or "failed to connect Network unreachable"

While trying to access staffing or aggregator-service through (Resources-service), below errors are> received:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl exec -it resources-deployment-6b98d47b5b-ts674 cmd
>
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.864]
>   (c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\app\resources>curl http://172.20.101.110:8081/swagger/index.html
>   curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.20.101.110 port 8081: Network unreachable
>
> C:\app\resources>curl http://aggregator-service:8081/swagger/index.html
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: aggregator-service
>
> C:\app\resources>curl http://staffing-service:8080/swagger/index.html
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: staffing-service
>
> C:\app\resources>curl http://172.20.5.156:8080/swagger/index.html
>   curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.20.5.156 port 8080: Network unreachable
>
> C:\app\resources>ping 10.91.24.250
>
> Pinging 10.91.24.250 with 32 bytes of data:
>   PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Code is very simple, here are the complete details.

Its a mixed environment with two windows nodes and two linux nodes. However for the time being requirement is to deploy the below applications on windows nodes only. Infrastructure is deployed on EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service) provided by AWS.

Three backend (aspnet) services are:-

1. Staffing.yaml file with type LoadBalancer.
2. Resources.Yaml having type NodePort
3. Aggregator.Yaml having type NodePort

Requirement is that Resources API should be able to connect to both Aggregator and Staffing services. And Staffing API too can connect to any of the services (Resources and Aggregator)

> Deployment and Services YAML file are:- 
>   Staffing.yaml file

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: staffing-deployment
      #namespace: staffing-kube-system
      labels:
        app: staffing-app
    spec:
      replicas: 2
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: staffing-app
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: staffing-app
        spec:
          nodeSelector:
           beta.kubernetes.io/os: windows
           #failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone: us-east-1a
          containers:
          - name: staffing-app
            ports:
             - name: http
               containerPort: 8080
            image: test/staffing:v1
    ##########################
    #Staffing.service.yaml file
    --- 
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: staffing-app
      name: staffing-service
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
    spec: 
      ports: 
        - 
          name: http
          #nodePort: 30475
          port: 8080
          protocol: TCP
          targetPort: 8080
        - 
          name: https
          #nodePort: 30476
          port: 443
          protocol: TCP
          targetPort: 44346
      selector: 
        app: staffing-app
      type: LoadBalancer
```

> resources.service.deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: resources-deployment
  #namespace: staffing-kube-system
  labels:
    app: resources-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: resources-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: resources-app
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
       beta.kubernetes.io/os: windows
       #failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone: us-east-1a
      containers:
      - name: resources-app
        ports:
         - name: http
           containerPort: 8001
        image: test/resources:v1
################
#resources.service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: resources-app
  name: resources-service
 spec: 
  ports: 
    - 
      name: http
      #nodePort: 30475
      port: 8001
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8001
    - 
      name: https
      #nodePort: 30476
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 44345
  selector: 
    app: resources-app
  type: NodePort
```

> aggregator.service.deplpoyment.yaml

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: aggegator-deployment
      #namespace: staffing-kube-system
      labels:
        app: aggegator-app
    spec:
      replicas: 2
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: aggregator-app
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: aggregator-app
        spec:
          nodeSelector:
           beta.kubernetes.io/os: windows
           #failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone: us-east-1a
          containers:
          - name: aggregator-app
            ports:
             - name: http
               containerPort: 8001
            image: test/aggregator:v1
 ################
    #aggregator.service.yaml
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Service
        metadata: 
          labels: 
            app: resources-app
          name: resources-service
         spec: 
          ports: 
            - 
              name: http
              #nodePort: 30475
              port: 8001
              protocol: TCP
              targetPort: 8001
            - 
              name: https
              #nodePort: 30476
              port: 443
              protocol: TCP
              targetPort: 44345
          selector: 
            app: resources-app
          type: NodePort
```

> Output of Pods and services

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE                           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
aggegator-deployment-64497699d-792dd    1/1     Running   0          2d12h   10.91.25.210   ip-10-91-25-125.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
aggegator-deployment-64497699d-tfsww    1/1     Running   0          2d12h   10.91.24.250   ip-10-91-24-148.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
resources-deployment-6b98d47b5b-7x8fv   1/1     Running   0          2d13h   10.91.25.197   ip-10-91-25-125.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
resources-deployment-6b98d47b5b-ts674   1/1     Running   0          2d13h   10.91.24.122   ip-10-91-24-148.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
staffing-deployment-797464966d-4j4nc    1/1     Running   0          2d16h   10.91.24.224   ip-10-91-24-148.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>
staffing-deployment-797464966d-mrw7x    1/1     Running   0          2d17h   10.91.24.113   ip-10-91-24-148.ec2.internal   <none>           <none>




C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get services -o wide
NAME                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                                        PORT(S)                        AGE     SELECTOR
aggregator-service           NodePort       172.20.101.110   <none>                                                                             8081:32246/TCP,443:30240/TCP   2d12h   app=aggregator-app
kubernetes                   ClusterIP      172.20.0.1       <none>                                                                             443/TCP                        21d     <none>
resources-service            NodePort       172.20.228.37    <none>                                                                             8001:31365/TCP,443:31686/TCP   2d13h   app=resources-app
staffing-service             LoadBalancer   172.20.5.156     internal-af561cd570d0d11eab0c00a891642f9b-874414568.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com    8080:30010/TCP,443:31327/TCP   2d17h   app=staffing-app



C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get pods --selector="app=resources-app"
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
resources-deployment-6b98d47b5b-7x8fv   1/1     Running   0          2d21h
resources-deployment-6b98d47b5b-ts674   1/1     Running   0          2d21h

C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get pods --selector="app=aggregator-app"
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
aggegator-deployment-64497699d-792dd   1/1     Running   0          2d20h
aggegator-deployment-64497699d-tfsww   1/1     Running   0          2d20h

C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get pods --selector="app=staffing-app"
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
staffing-deployment-797464966d-4j4nc   1/1     Running   0          3d
staffing-deployment-797464966d-mrw7x   1/1     Running   0          3d1h


C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get endpoints
NAME                         ENDPOINTS                                                             AGE
aggregator-service           10.91.24.250:8081,10.91.25.210:8081,10.91.24.250:44347 + 1 more...    2d20h
kubernetes                   10.91.24.167:443,10.91.25.120:443                                     22d
resources-service            10.91.24.122:8001,10.91.25.197:8001,10.91.24.122:44345 + 1 more...    2d21h
staffing-service             10.91.24.113:44346,10.91.24.224:44346,10.91.24.113:8080 + 1 more...   3d2h

> Kubectl logs

C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-8455f84f99-d6v75   1/1     Running   0          21d
coredns-8455f84f99-jf7tz   1/1     Running   0          21d

C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl logs coredns-8455f84f99-jf7tz  -n kube-system
.:53
2019-11-03T14:27:30.347Z [INFO] CoreDNS-1.3.1
2019-11-03T14:27:30.347Z [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.10.8, 6b56a9c9
CoreDNS-1.3.1
linux/amd64, go1.10.8, 6b56a9c9
2019-11-03T14:27:30.347Z [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 86a350d0c3832da65c10531b445c45d5
[INFO] Reloading
2019-11-25T07:00:09.649Z [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = ebe4e401326d5dac294cde91064e2e76
[INFO] Reloading complete
2019-11-25T11:38:44.107Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57354 - 8232 "A IN . udp 17 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 92 0.000084547s
2019-11-25T11:38:44.113Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57364 - 33842 "A IN . udp 17 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 92 0.000059248s
2019-11-25T11:39:15.287Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57366 - 23694 "A IN v10.events.data.microsoft.com. udp 47 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 284 0.003154278s
2019-11-25T11:39:15.331Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57366 - 23694 "A IN v10.events.data.microsoft.com. udp 47 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 284 0.069842673s
2019-11-25T11:39:15.615Z [INFO] 10.91.25.125:61221 - 24722 "A IN v10.events.data.microsoft.com. udp 47 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 284 0.000102425s
2019-11-25T11:39:17.575Z [INFO] 10.91.25.125:61223 - 8379 "A IN v10.events.data.microsoft.com. udp 47 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 284 0.000096859s
2019-11-25T11:39:18.925Z [INFO] 10.91.25.125:61239 - 49217 "A IN settings-win.data.microsoft.com. udp 49 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 176 0.030653295s
2019-11-25T11:39:19.006Z [INFO] 10.91.25.125:61239 - 49217 "A IN settings-win.data.microsoft.com. udp 49 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 176 0.142995164s
2019-11-25T11:39:19.205Z [INFO] 10.91.25.125:61241 - 25186 "A IN settings-win.data.microsoft.com. udp 49 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 176 0.000088335s
2019-11-25T11:39:43.422Z [INFO] 10.91.25.125:61257 - 26043 "A IN . udp 17 false 512" SERVFAIL qr,rd,ra 17 0.013510742s
2019-11-25T11:39:44.129Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57368 - 382 "A IN . udp 17 false 512" SERVFAIL qr,rd,ra 17 0.013958603s
2019-11-25T11:39:44.270Z [INFO] 10.91.25.125:61261 - 53992 "A IN . udp 17 false 512" SERVFAIL qr,rd,ra 17 0.014368787s
2019-11-25T11:39:44.981Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57370 - 41136 "A IN . udp 17 false 512" SERVFAIL qr,rd,ra 17 0.014143535s
2019-11-25T11:40:15.649Z [INFO] 10.91.25.125:61231 - 53428 "A IN ctldl.windowsupdate.com. udp 41 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 355 0.013625947s
2019-11-25T11:40:45.838Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57372 - 36065 "A IN . udp 17 false 512" SERVFAIL qr,rd,ra 17 0.013761424s
2019-11-25T11:40:46.688Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57382 - 26755 "A IN . udp 17 false 512" SERVFAIL qr,rd,ra 17 0.01357897s
2019-11-25T11:40:51.896Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57388 - 607 "A IN v10.events.data.microsoft.com. udp 47 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 284 0.033610722s
2019-11-25T11:40:52.006Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57388 - 607 "A IN v10.events.data.microsoft.com. udp 47 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 284 0.11348618s
2019-11-25T11:41:46.839Z [INFO] 10.91.25.125:61227 - 9202 "A IN . udp 17 false 512" SERVFAIL qr,rd,ra 17 0.013585559s
2019-11-25T11:41:47.553Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57339 - 12070 "A IN . udp 17 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 92 0.001922224s
2019-11-25T11:41:48.403Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57341 - 52311 "A IN . udp 17 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 92 0.000091287s
2019-11-25T11:42:04.827Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57343 - 23836 "A IN v10.events.data.microsoft.com. udp 47 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 284 0.028061963s
2019-11-25T11:42:04.827Z [INFO] 10.91.24.148:57343 - 23836 "A IN v10.events.data.microsoft.com. udp 47 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 284 0.004729734s
2019-11-25T11:42:13.855Z [hINFO] 10.91.24.148:57344 - 62298 "A IN ctldl.windowsupdate.com. udp 41 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 540 0.012435227s
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a service called `aggregator-service` in the same namespace where the pod from where you are trying to reach the service?

Comment: Describe each service to check if the endpoint to each pod is mapped

Comment: @suren Yes they are all on the same **default** namespace.

`[NAMESPACE     NAME                         
default       aggregator-service-ip        
default       kubernetes                   
default       resources-service            
default       resources-service-ip         
default       staffing-service             
default       windows-server-iis-service   
kube-system   kube-controller-manager      
kube-system   kube-dns                     
kube-system   kube-scheduler               
kube-system   vpc-admission-webhook ] `

Comment: @paltaa yes each service is mapped to a pod, please see the same in the output of pods and services provided above.
<br/>
`C:\WINDOWS\system32>kubectl get pods --selector="app=aggregator-app"
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
aggegator-deployment-64497699d-792dd   1/1     Running   0          2d20h
aggegator-deployment-64497699d-tfsww   1/1     Running   0          2d20h`

Comment: if you kubectl exec -ti <any-pod> bash, and then telnet <pod-ip> port, for the cluster ip you are trying to reach does it work? are you sure that each pod has the related pods opened?

Comment: @paltaa After narrowing it down, the problem was one of the window nodes from where none of the containers were able to resolve the DNS . However with the other windows node, hostname was being resolved and able to curl/ping other services.
Further, we terminated this faulty node and let the new one spin up, at that point all the pods moved to a working node. To balance the pods some were killed and spin up again to have pods running on a new window node. But now that had previously been working then started failing DNS lookups.

Comment: Now, random containers on any of the nodes are not able to resolve the hostname.

Comment: Thanks @paltaa for your response. There was an issue with the nodes created on private cloud using EKS or some dns polices were creating an issue. Problem has not been resolved yet. However, when the same setup is created on public cloud it worked.

However, not sure on public cloud why a NodePort (serviceA) was not able to connect to ClusterIP (serviceB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was within a definition of a service where ports defined in Kubernetes file were in conflicts with what was defined in a code.